# How could West Berlin had access West Germany/world while the wall was up?

Tags: berlin-wall

According to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Wall), West Berlin could still access West Germany/World while the wall was up:

> ...he (JFK) was relieved that the East Germans and the Soviets had only divided
> Berlin without taking any action against West Berlin's access to the West

Considering that the wall was fully circling West Berlin, and that West Berlin was fully inside East Germany, how could it (West Berlin) "access" the West?

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. We expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.For example, what is wrong with [Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Berlin)?

Comment: "West Berlin was 100 miles (161 kilometres) east and north of the Inner German border and only accessible by land from West Germany by narrow rail and highway corridors. It consisted of the American, British, and French occupation sectors established in 1945. " _[Wikipedia:WestBerlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_Berlin#:~:text=West%20Berlin%20was%20100%20miles,narrow%20rail%20and%20highway%20corridors.&text=The%20Berlin%20Wall%2C%20built%20in,until%20it%20fell%20in%201989.)_

Comment: In the same way that you do for a highway with a toll. You drive up to the toll booth, pay the fee (show your ID) and pass through. After 1971, this was very easy, before that it could take hours on each side (depending on the political climate).

Comment: Something most people don't realise is that the U-Bahn, Berlins underground transit system, still regularly ran between east and west Berlin - you had to be careful not to go too far on it lest you accidentally crossed the border and fell under East German control...

Comment: @Moo That was actually no problem at all, since on the 2 lines the stations in east Berlin had been closed and the trains didn't stop. Exception was Friedrichstraße, where the train did stop. After getting off you had walk through a tunnel to get to the passport control in the main station. This problem existed **before** the the wall was built. Then it was not always clear when you crossed over with bus, tram, U- and S-Bahn.

Comment: @MarkJohnson it was a problem for us military families, a few accidentally did the trip while I was there and were detained until western military police were contacted and forced the issue with their Soviet counterparts, who overruled the East Germans.

Comment: @Moo As stated, the trains didn't stop other than in Friedrichstraße. Even when changing from the U-Bahn up to the S-Bahn going west, there were no checks. Your generalized statement is false and misleading. For US military and their dependents, who had standing orders not to get off or transfer at Friedrichstraße, doing so nevertheless is no reason to imply that it was a general problem for the 99.999% that did so daily.

Comment: @MarkJohnson yeah, I lived through that and had a friend detained, but sure, my comment is misleading and false.  Lets all bow down to your assertions instead.

Comment: @Moo Well I transfered between the U-Bahn to the S-Bahn twice every workday for over a year in the mid 1970's, so I'm very familiar with that situation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128650/discussion-between-moo-and-mark-johnson).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After World War II, four allied powers divided Germany into four occupation zones. The American, British, and French zones became the Federal Republic of Germany (BRD/FRG, West Germany) and the Soviet zone became the German Democratic Republic (DDR/GDR, East Germany). Berlin had a special status, and it was itself divided into four sectors. The three western Sectors were not quite part of the Federal Republic, not quite apart from it. For instance, there was no draft into the FRG army, and the allied commanders were the supreme authority.

At times, the Soviet Union and the GDR government (which took Soviet orders in this regard) tried to blockade West Berlin. The most famous event was the blockade which led to the [Berlin Airlift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Blockade). Other events happened [1958](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Crisis_of_1958%E2%80%931959) and [1961](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Crisis_of_1961). The US appeared ready to defend West Berlin, potentially starting World War III, and the Soviets never *quite* pushed that much.

Some highways, rail lines, rivers/canals and air lanes were designated as [transit lanes](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:DDR_Transit041.jpg), with visa-free travel. This was improved in a [1972](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transit_Agreement_(1972)) treaty. The GDR earned money from transit fees, so it was in their interest to promote travel. Of course they were also afraid of East Germans trying to escape, and West Germans telling the Easterners what Communists did not want them to hear.

That being said, the *civilian* access to and from West Berlin was never quite as secure as the access of the Western Allied military. The government of Berlin maintained the [Senatsreserve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senate_Reserve), a stockpile to hedge against another blockade. And some Germans would fly to the West rather than take a car.

Comment: Even western military access was never ... secure - we drove the corridor a few times, got stopped by East German police more than once, and the standard routine was to show western military ID and refuse to talk to anyone until the East Germans summoned a Soviet representative (legally, East German police had zero jurisdiction over Allied military personnel and their families, Soviets had to deal with us).  And we had our own stockpile of food reserves called FRIS on base, they rotated stock every 90 days so you could get cheap good quality frozen meat etc on a regular basis.

Comment: Even when we travelled on the British Military Train from Berlin to West Germany, the doors and windows were locked shut for the entire duration of the trip.